# I'm using the TMDB API, and when clicking on the gallery image, I want to redirect to another page and display it

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm having difficulty displaying the image in full screen after clicking on it:

ROUTES

```
ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route element={<App />}>
          <Route path='/' element={<Home />} />
          <Route path='/top-rated' element={<TopRated />} />
          <Route path='/popular' element={<Popular />} />
          <Route path='/trending' element={<Trending />} />
          <Route path='/in-theaters' element={<Theaters />} />
          <Route path='movie/:id' element={<Movies />} />
          <Route path="/movie/:id/images" element={<MovieImagesGallery />} />
          <Route path="/movie/:id/credits" element={<CastCrew />} />
          <Route path='search' element={<Search />} />
          <Route path='movie/:id/images/:index' element={<ImageView />} />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>
)
```

GALLERY

```
const MovieImages = () => {
  const { id } = useParams();
  const [images, setImages] = useState([]);
  const [movieDetails, setMovieDetails] = useState({ title: '' }); 
  
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchMovieDetails(id).then((movieData) => {
      setMovieDetails(movieData);
    });

    fetchImages(id).then((imageData) => {
      setImages(imageData.backdrops);
    });
  }, [id]);

  return (
    <main className="container-movie-images">
      <Link to={`/movie/${id}`}>
        <p>{movieDetails.title} <span> ({new Date(movieDetails.release_date).getFullYear()}) </span> </p>
      </Link>
      
      <h2>Gallery</h2>
      <div className="image-gallery">
        {images.map((image) => (
          <MovieImageGallery key={image.id} image={image} />
        ))}
      </div>
    </main>
  );
}
export default MovieImages;

export const MovieImageGallery = ({ image }) => {
  console.log('Image ID:', image.id);
  return (
    <div className="movie-card">
      <Link to={`/movie/${image.id}/images/${image.index} `}>
        <img 
          src={imgApi.defaults.baseURL + image.file_path} 
          alt={`Imagem ${image.name}`} 
        />
      </Link>
    </div>
  );
};










IMAGE VIEW
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import { fetchImages } from '../../services/GaleryImages';

const ImageView = () => {
  const { id } = useParams();
  const [image, setImage] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchImages(id).then((imageData) => {
      console.log('Image Data:', imageData);
      setImage(imageData);
    });
  }, [id]);

  if (!image) {
    return <p>Carregando imagem...</p>;
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Imagem Individual</h2>
      <img src={image.url} alt={`Image ${id}`} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default ImageView;
```

The URL, when clicked on the image, becomes: http://localhost:5173/movie/undefined/images/undefined The page loads, but it doesn't display the selected image, and the alt text for the images, which should receive the ID, shows "undefined."